# Rails: "rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 4.2.

In my rails project directory, I have a frontend directory:

```
/railsproject/frontend
/railsproject/frontend/styles
/railsproject/frontend/styles/main.scss
```

I have added `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("frontend","styles")` to `application.rb`.

In `/railsproject/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`:

```
@import "main.scss";
```

**Everything works fine in Development mode**.

But when I try to precompile for production, it fails:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: main.scss.
(sass):17
/Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.15/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
/Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.15/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
/Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.15/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
/Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.15/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
etc...
```

Comment: Besides adding this to asset paths, I believe you would still need to either include in your manifest file (my preference) or add to your assets precompile directive.  Did you do one of those?  The first item in [this great post](https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/116-12-tips-for-the-rails-asset-pipeline) on the asset pipeline provides more detail.